# PayuMoney India integration with Node js

Tags: node.js, payment-gateway, payumoney

I am trying to integrate an nodejs app to integrate with PayUMoney. I followed the instructions and example code for php and implemented in node.js, but I am getting **checksum error**.

> Error. We are sorry we are unable to process your payment.
>
> Checksum Failed. Please contact your merchant.

here is the code. frontend

```
<form method="post" id="payu-payment-form" action="https://test.payu.in/_payment">
    <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="hash"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="marchentKey"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="asc123"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1000" />
    <input type="hidden" name="productinfo" value="Product 1"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="Amit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="abc@gmail.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="123423233" />
    <input type="hidden" name="surl" value="http://localhost/success"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="furl" value="http://localhost/fail"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="service_provider" value="payu_paisa" />
    <button class="" type="submit" formtarget="_blank" >Buy</button>
</form>
```

Node.js

```
var txnid='asc123';
var amount=1000;
var produnctinfo='Product 1';
var firstname='Amit';
var email='abc@gmail.com';
var phone='123423233';
var surl='http://localhost/success';
var furl='http://localhost/fail';
var service_provider='payu_paisa';
var string = marchentKey +'|' +txnid+ '|' +amount+'|'+productinfo+'|'+firstname+'|'+email+'|'+phone+'|'+ surl +'|'+furl+'|'+service_provider+'|||||||'+salt;
var hash=sha512(string);
```

Comment: `"marchentKey"` - there's a typo here.

Comment: I intentionally put "marchentKey" here.. I am using my original test key, salt and generated hash in html form

Comment: I even tried with test key and salt that i found for testing purpose. key 'JBZaLc' and salt 'GQs7yium'

Comment: Hi @optimus did you complete the payment with payUmoney.

Comment: I'm having some problem with success and failure page can u share a link for that Thanks.

Comment: Hi @vishnumishra I did competed payUmoney. Can you please give more details of your errors. I already shared my working code as an accepted answer below.

Comment: Thanks @optimus I did payUmoney.

Comment: @optimus         Hi, I am also trying to integrate PayUmoney payment gateway. But I am not understanding how you are calculating the hash.
I mean do we have `sha512()` method in node.js or you are using a module for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Test Key & Salt in PHP Integration kit was not working. So using my own test key and salt and calculating correct hash its working fine.

Previously I was calculating hash with phone, surl, furl and service_provider. But it should be like

```
var string = marchentKey +'|' +txnid+ '|' +amount+'|'+productinfo+'|'+firstname+'|'+email+'|||||||||||'+salt;
var hash=sha512(string);
```

if you posting variables which are not mention in their documentation i.e user defined variables then you should include those varibles as udf1, udf2..

```
var string = marchentKey +'|' +txnid+ '|' +amount+'|'+productinfo+'|'+firstname+'|'+email+'|'+udf1+'|'+udf2+'|||||||||'+salt;
var hash=sha512(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Leave the Service Provider field blank:

```
var service_provider='';
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your posting the userdefined variables with custom name. 
Use udf1 instead of using service_provider.

```
<form method="post" id="payu-payment-form" action="https://test.payu.in/_payment">
    <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="hash"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="marchentKey"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="asc123"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1000" />
    <input type="hidden" name="productinfo" value="Product 1"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="Amit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="abc@gmail.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="surl" value="http://localhost/success"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="furl" value="http://localhost/fail"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="123423233" />
    <input type="hidden" name="udf1" value="payu_paisa" />
    <button class="" type="submit" formtarget="_blank" >Buy</button>
</form>
```

The hash calculation

```
hash=sha512(key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1||||||||||SALT);
```

Comment: by using udfs, it is giving "Sorry, Some Problem Occurred." error

Comment: According to my experience we can't use custom names for userdefined variables

Comment: In PayU documentation phone, surl, furl and service_provider are compulsory fields but in their PHP example they were not using these field to calculate hash. udf1, udf2.. fields are user defined fields, they are not for replacing phone, surl, furl and service_provider.

Comment: phone, surl and furl are mandatory fields. But service_provider is not. If you want to mention it in your post parameters use user defined variables,

Comment: service_provider is also a compulsory field.

Comment: https://github.com/payu-india/payu_docs/blob/master/Integration%20Document%20Version%202.5.pdf

Comment: I am using this document [link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.uservoice.com/assets/074/080/407/original/PayUMoney_Technical_Integration_Document.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=14D6VH0N6B73PJ6VE382&Expires=1502319395&Signature=P9kYKXLkEcxCx0PnGufPLhzoXGQ%3D) PayU provided this document with PHP integration kit

Comment: but it seems there are lots of version of PayU integration document

Comment: BTW it is working now. First problem was that I was using the key & salt which was mention in documentation, but that is no longer working and second problem was, I was using phone, surl, curl, service_provider for creating hash.

Comment: @AbhilashKm     Ho can we calculate hash in node.js?

Comment: @AbhilashKm     Thanks a lot, I've figured out that thing. Can you help me out with the response code? I want to fetch transaction response code so that I can perform further operations. I have sent mail to `payUmoney`, they said to use `webhooks` in order to get `response codes`.